# What is the best 1.9 magic fishing rod for catching treasure?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Since 1.9 made afk fishing a very easy and profitable endeavour (because you can use magic mending/unbreaking rods and ditch the rod storage/dispenser mechanism) and on top of mending you can use luck of the sea / lure and mending+unbreaking.

I have been using the following rod to afk fish:

> Unbreaking III
>   Luck of The Sea III
>       Lure III
>       Mending

But I came across [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/2czxv9/best_fishing_rod_enchants_to_get_treasure/), with a very detailed analysis:

> Based on this I calculate the average time (seconds, rounded to nearest integer) between treasures for each Lure/Luck combination:

```
Lure↓\Luck→     0       1       2       3
          0     500     417     357     313
          1     500     400     333     286
          2     583     438     350     292
          3     750     500     375     300
```

> As you can see, Lure 1 and Luck of the Sea 3 is the best combination for time efficient treasure finding.

There were several changes to fishing in 1.9. What is the best magic fishing rod for catching treasure?

Comment: Again, there is no table markup. SE recommends using code markup.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the right fishing rod. There is one change in 1.9 that made the reddit post obsolete:

[Minecraft 1.9 Changelog](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting):

> 15w43c    Lure no longer affects loot.

It means that the reduction of 1% per level on treasure is no longer in effect. So the faster you fish, the more treasure you get.

**The best fishing rod for catching treasure then has**

> Luck of the Sea III
> Lure III

Adding mending and unbreaking while *a good choice to save experience points*, are irrelevant to the chances of treasure.

Answer (score 1):

On a world without plugins or commands I AFK fished for 2 hours using this fishing rod:

- Mending I
- Lure III
- Luck of the Sea III
- Unbreaking III

I used all the books I got and I got my Diamond Armor all Protection IV, I got my bow to Power 5, Infinity, Mending, Flame, And Punch 2, My Pickaxe became eff. 5 fortune 3 Mending and Unbreaking 3.

I recommend this strategy for AFK fishing if you want to get good gear if you have the patience.

Comment: How did you get both Mending and Infinity on a bow?  I thought they could not be on the same bow without using commands.

Comment: Unbreaking and Mending on the same item seem redundant.

Comment: @DrewNoakes They are _very much not_ redundant, as `Unbreaking III` will reduce the amount of XP that `Mending` sucks away by 75% — Unbreaking makes each "durability" point work for more uses, but does _not_ increase the amount of XP it takes to restore one — so it's *significantly* more efficient. Even if you can just put `Unbreaking I` on your `Mending` equipment, **that's still a 50% reduction in XP LOE, for the same usage of the tool**. The enchantments synergize *extremely* well.